# Path Traversal Vulnerability in Java

Tags: java, security, gitlab

I'm trying to fix Path Traversal Vulnerability raised by Gitlab SAST in the Java Source code. I tried using multiple ways which are present on the web to fix it but still, Gitlab marked it as Path Traversal Vulnerability. The file name we're getting from the properties file and setting it into the Config class. A

The actual source code:

```
public Config(String filename) throws IOException {
            setFile(new File(filename));
    
}
```

what we have tried so far:

```
public Config(String filename) throws IOException {
    if(filename.indexOf( "../" ) == -1) {
        String pathUsingCanonical = Paths.get(filename).toFile().getCanonicalPath();
        String pathUsingAbsolute = Paths.get(filename).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
        if(pathUsingCanonical.equals(pathUsingAbsolute)) {
            setFile(new File(filename));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If path is `/this/is/some/path/../dir`, it should resolve it to `/this/is/some/dir`. Then just check if it is allowed to access files in that path.

Comment: First off, *is* this actually a vulnerability in your case? Just because user input can set an arbitrary path this isn’t necessarily a vulnerability — unless, of course, you *want* to restrict valid paths. In that case I agree with @kiner_shah: construct the path, and afterwards check whether the path has an allowed prefix.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this is the code we have in our code base and the GitLab is showing it as Path Traversal Vulnerability. Not sure, why it's showing as a vulnerability if we're getting the file path from the props file and then creating a File object by using it. Can we mark it as a false positive in the tool?